# git aws.push: 'aws.push' is not a git command

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, push, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

From my site/application directory:

```
$ git aws.push
git: 'aws.push' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

`git --help` doesn't help.

All the posts I have read were written before EB Command Line Interface (CLI) 3.x was a thing.

I followed the official instructions here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-set-up.html

And here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.sdlc.html

Unfortunately, the latter still says to:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:<path to unzipped eb CLI package>/eb/linux/python2.7/
```

But I don't know that path because I didn't download and unzip a package. I installed **awsebcli** using **pip**, as per the instructions on the first link above.

Everything else seems to be in place. I have WordPress configured and running locally (OS X/Apache) with the remote RDS MySQL database. Not that the contents of the application matter. My AWS IAM credentials are entered (via the prompt).

`eb create` commands works! And it uploads my local application (files) perfectly. But I don't want to create a new application/environment. I already have one and I just want to `git push` my files to it.

**1. How can I find `/eb/linux/python2.7/` so I can set that PATH?**
**2. Is there some other reason/solution?**

Answer (score 10):

Solution:

```
eb deploy
```

Turns out `eb --help` WAS a big help.

But stupidly enough, it was as I sat there staring blankly at the screen that a memory jogged and I recalled seeing the command `eb deploy` somewhere else (on a website).

I tried it. It worked.

If you are using *AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI 3.x*…

**Do not use `git aws.push`!**

**Instead, use `eb deploy` to update your application version.**

Comment: hey, but what if I have a sqlite db running? every eb deploy will destry it. How to prevent that?

Comment: This was too long ago for me to remember. But hope someone else can help you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I was using aws.push to update my application. Then I moved to a new computer and I had to set everything up again.

You can use

```
eb deploy
```

However, depending upon how you have your project setup, you might need to map your deployment to a branch. Use:

```
eb branch
```

I was in a bind and wanted to make sure that I did not screw up a deployment by introducing any new issues into the production environment and I wanted to use:

```
git aws.push
```

This can still be done.

Download the deprecated version of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool [here](http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743)

Then from within your repo run **AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh**. You can find this file in the zip file you just downloaded, AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.4 / AWSDevTools / Linux

Now run

```
git aws.config
```

Once configured you should be able to run git aws.push without any problems.

**I am now using eb deploy, but I was in a bind and had never used it and did not have time to test it. So this worked for me.**