# aws.push does not work

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Although I have `eb init` if I try to `aws.push` I get this error:

```
git: 'aws.push' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

How to start using `aws.push` and what's the difference between `aws.push` and `eb deploy` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws.push` was seen in [older version of Eb CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli.html):

> `eb push` and `git aws.push`: EB CLI does not include the commands `eb push` or `git aws.push`. **The commands have been replaced with the command `eb deploy`.**

So, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28706078/6309), use `eb deploy`.